# Where to see all possible properties for the resources for Azure Resource Manager templates?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-rm-template

In ARM templates, we configure multiple properties for a resource.
For example for AKS - (taken from [AKS Quickstart template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.kubernetes/aks/azuredeploy.json))

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
      "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('dnsPrefix')]",
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSizeGB')]",
            "count": "[parameters('agentCount')]",
            "vmSize": "[parameters('agentVMSize')]",
            "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
            "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks"
          }
        ],
        "linuxProfile": {
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('linuxAdminUsername')]",
          "ssh": {
            "publicKeys": [
              {
                "keyData": "[parameters('sshRSAPublicKey')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, there are properties like dnsPrefix, agentPoolProfiles (and its sub properties like osDiskSizeGB), linuxProfile, etc

Where are these properties documented? Where can I find the list of all possible properties that I can configure for a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the relevant documentation in the [**`ManagedClusterProperties object`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?tabs=json#ManagedClusterProperties)

The trick here is to get the resource name and you can find the relevant documentation from the [ARM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/) by mapping the reosurce